# Using sed to eliminate a specific string

Tags: sed

I appreciate your help with this problem. I like to eliminate everything that is not a specific pattern from a string.

For example, below I like to **eliminate** everything that is **not "5TTGTC"**.

But as seen here **^5TTGTC** is not right. I used different combinations of ^(), ^{}, ^[], but none gave me what I am looking for. Appreciate your feedback!

```
 echo ".,..,...+5TTGTC...+5TTGCC.+5TTGTC,,.,.,,.,+5ttgtc,.,,.,.+5TTGTC.+5TTGTC,..+5TTGTC" | sed 's/^5TTGTC//g'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Outside of a character class ([ ]), `^` references the beginning of the line.  
Should '5ttgtc' also match?  
What should the result look like?

Comment: I got it! This is how you eliminate everything but "5TTGTC" from your string (and deduplicate the result at the same time):
`echo "5TTGTC"`

Comment: A simple negated character set will not work [here](https://regex101.com/r/qauuMz/2).

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following command if you want **case sensitivity**:

`echo ".,..,...+5TTGTC...+5TTGCC.+5TTGTC,,.,.,,.,+5ttgtc,.,,.,.+5TTGTC.+5TTGTC,..+5TTGTC" | sed -r 's/(5TTGTC)|[,.A-Za-z+0-9]/\1/g'`

The code above prints:

```
5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC
```

---

The regular expression used above uses [alternation](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) to capture what you are interested in. 
We match and capture what we are interested in (`5TTGCC`) and we match everything that is not the substring, in this case characters `,.A-Za-z+0-9`.

You can check the behaviour of the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/pOz4Xj/3).

---

As pointed out by @EdMorton, the command can be simplified to:

`echo ".,..,...+5TTGTC...+5TTGCC.+5TTGTC,,.,.,,.,+5ttgtc,.,,.,.+5TTGTC.+5TTGTC,..+5TTGTC" | sed -r 's/(5TTGTC)|./\1/g'`

You can [try this here](https://regex101.com/r/pOz4Xj/2).

For compatibility across *sed* versions the **-r** flag can be replaced by the **-E** flag.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ed. Yes, matching `.` is simpler. Good point, I will edit my answer with that information, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't make it very clear what you are trying to achieve.
One way to get where you are trying to go could be the `-o` option in `grep`.

`echo ".,..,...+5TTGTC...+5TTGCC.+5TTGTC,,.,.,,.,+5ttgtc,.,,.,.+5TTGTC.+5TTGTC,..+5TTGTC" | grep -o '5TTGTC'`

Output:

`5TTGTC
5TTGTC
5TTGTC
5TTGTC
5TTGTC`

You can then change `5TTGTC` into a pattern, e.g. `grep -o '[0-9]TT[AG]GTC'`

Comment: grep also works here yes, but OP is looking for a sed replacement pattern.

Comment: well, OP doesn't actually make very clear what the problem to be solved is. `sed` may only be in there because it's what they think solves the problem, not because it is what they actually want to use.

Comment: *I like to eliminate everything that is not "5TTGTC"*

Answer (score 1):

With any sed:

```
$  echo ".,..,...+5TTGTC...+5TTGCC.+5TTGTC,,.,.,,.,+5ttgtc,.,,.,.+5TTGTC.+5TTGTC,..+5TTGTC" |
sed 's/#//g; s/5TTGTC/#/g; s/[^#]//g; s/#/5TTGTC/g'
5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC
```

With any awk:

```
$ echo ".,..,...+5TTGTC...+5TTGCC.+5TTGTC,,.,.,,.,+5ttgtc,.,,.,.+5TTGTC.+5TTGTC,..+5TTGTC" |
awk -v str='5TTGTC' '{gsub(str,"\n"); gsub(/[^\n]/,""); gsub(/\n/,str)}1'
5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC5TTGTC
```